# Downloading a file from the internet

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download an MP3 file from the internet to an SD card in Android.
I know the desktop Java equivalent, but because I want to take advantage of some interesting looking Android based SDKs so I decided to try my hand at writing a mobile app.

Was a lot to learn, and I feel like I skipped a lot of steps.

I did something like this in Java:

```
    File outputSong = new File("outputFolder/testSong.mp3");
    is1 = new URL(currentSong).openStream();
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(is1);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputSong);
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    fos.close();
```

But Android didn't like that. I looked here, the developer.android website, and some internet tutorials on how to deal with files. I tried doing this:

```
    String currentSong = "http://nyan.90g.org/e/1/50/9f755b639fa518e7f5580b648c7b2f60.mp3";
    String currentArtwork = "http://moefou.90g.org/wiki_cover/000/00/29/000002938.jpg";
    String fileName = "";
    URLConnection conn = new URL(currentArtwork).openConnection();
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    int lastSlash = conn.getURL().toString().lastIndexOf('/');
    if (lastSlash>=0)
        fileName = conn.getURL().toString().substring(lastSlash+1);
    if (fileName.equals(""))
        fileName = conn.getURL().hashCode() + ".jpg";
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
    File outputArtwork = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputArtwork);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    byte[] data = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while((bytesRead = bis.read(data, 0, data.length)) >= 0) {
        bos.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    bos.close();
    bis.close();
```

I got it to work ONCE, and now I've been unsuccessful in trying to repeat the action. I got the manifest permissions in. I would be grateful if anybody could show me how they would go about this.

While I'm at it, everyone says to use logcat. Is that like printing to the console? That would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean with unsuccessful? Is there an exception thrown or something? 
And yes, logcat is where logging occurs, and thus where stacktraces are printed. It should be somewhere in your IDE, possibly under the 'DDMS' tab.

Comment: Sometimes nothing happens, sometimes I get a null pointer, but I know those resources are there, because the desktop version I've made loads every time without fail.

Comment: What can I do to see if certain things are null or not? Like a sys.out but for android?what I want to do is to embedd that picture into tue mp3

Comment: `System.out` works in Android (Though not very efficient), displays in the logcat. Use the `Log` class for logging.

Comment: I found out what's going on. I had to restart the emulator to see the changes in the media player and pictures applications.